I installed peewee but it does not support pysqlite in the peewee file
When I try to install it, I get this error.
Collecting pysqlite3
  Using cached pysqlite3-0.5.2.tar.gz (40 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pysqlite3
  Building wheel for pysqlite3 (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for pysqlite3 (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [41 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/pysqlite3
      copying pysqlite3/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/pysqlite3
      copying pysqlite3/dbapi2.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/pysqlite3
      running build_ext
      Builds a C extension linking against libsqlite3 library
      building 'pysqlite3._sqlite3' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/src
      clang -fno-strict-overflow -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -Qunused-arguments -DMODULE_NAME=\"pysqlite3.dbapi2\" -I/usr/include -I/Users/pc/Documents/GitHub/OCR/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12 -c src/blob.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/src/blob.o
      clang -fno-strict-overflow -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -Qunused-arguments -DMODULE_NAME=\"pysqlite3.dbapi2\" -I/usr/include -I/Users/pc/Documents/GitHub/OCR/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12 -c src/cache.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/src/cache.o
      clang -fno-strict-overflow -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -Qunused-arguments -DMODULE_NAME=\"pysqlite3.dbapi2\" -I/usr/include -I/Users/pc/Documents/GitHub/OCR/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12 -c src/connection.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/src/connection.o
      src/connection.c:1111:10: warning: 'sqlite3_create_window_function' is only available on macOS 10.15 or newer [-Wunguarded-availability-new]
          rc = sqlite3_create_window_function(
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3.h:5533:16: note: 'sqlite3_create_window_function' has been marked as being introduced in macOS 10.15 here, but the deployment target is macOS 10.9.0
      SQLITE_API int sqlite3_create_window_function(
                     ^
      src/connection.c:1111:10: note: enclose 'sqlite3_create_window_function' in a __builtin_available check to silence this warning
          rc = sqlite3_create_window_function(
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      src/connection.c:1385:10: error: call to undeclared function 'sqlite3_enable_load_extension'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
          rc = sqlite3_enable_load_extension(self->db, onoff);
               ^
      src/connection.c:1385:10: note: did you mean 'pysqlite_enable_load_extension'?
      src/connection.c:1372:18: note: 'pysqlite_enable_load_extension' declared here
      static PyObject* pysqlite_enable_load_extension(pysqlite_Connection* self, PyObject* args)
                       ^
      src/connection.c:1409:10: error: call to undeclared function 'sqlite3_load_extension'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
          rc = sqlite3_load_extension(self->db, extension_name, 0, &errmsg);
               ^
      src/connection.c:1409:10: note: did you mean 'pysqlite_load_extension'?
      src/connection.c:1395:18: note: 'pysqlite_load_extension' declared here
      static PyObject* pysqlite_load_extension(pysqlite_Connection* self, PyObject* args)
                       ^
      1 warning and 2 errors generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pysqlite3
Failed to build pysqlite3
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pysqlite3, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I deleted and reinstalled peewee and python but there was no improvement.

what command generates this error ? pip install pysqlite3 ?

yes, gives command to pip install pysqlite3

This has nothing to do with peewee. It looks like you're trying to install pysqlite3 (a replacement for the standard library sqlite3 module with a few additions) and you are missing the sqlite3 headers, which are required to compile it from source. You have three options:

Do nothing, just use peewee and be happy. It works great with the standard library sqlite3 module.
Install sqlite3 headers, e.g. apt-get install libsqlite3-dev on debian-based.
Install the pre-built binaries for x86-64 linux: pip install pysqlite3-binary. If you are on a different architecture you will, however, need to build from source.

The pysqlite3 readme doc is pretty clear: https://github.com/coleifer/pysqlite3/
Edit: I see now you're on apple. You'll want to install the sqlite3 headers, brew install sqlite3 or something similar.

Nothing has changed. Sqlite3 still doesn't work on peewee files.

There's no such thing as a peewee file.... This is 100% user error, my friend.

I installed the peewee library. Pysqlite3 in the library is not working, I wonder how this could be my fault? When I try to download it, it gives the error I wrote. Exactly my fault :D

Peewee does not need pysqlite3. If you want pysqlite3 to compile you need xcode and then to install the sqlite3 headers, e.g. brew install sqlite3 as in my answer.
